# Printing a line twice in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, printing

In the MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\section*{Version 1}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,1) -- (0,1) -- cycle;
\draw (1,0) -- (2,0) -- (2,1) -- (1,1) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\section*{Version 2}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (2,0) -- (2,1) -- (0,1) -- cycle;
\draw (1,0) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

both, version 1 and version 2, seem to produce the same result.

[image: Output of the MWE]

In version 1, however, the line from (1, 0) to (1, 1) is printed twice. Can this lead to any kind of problem when creating a hardcopy on a laser printer, on an offset printing machine or on another printing device?

I am asking this question because in more complex scenario based on various commands it may be diffucult to detect if the same line occurs twice in the Ti*k*Z picture.

Comment: I think I did have some issues with something similar to this... But, I seem to recall that the issue were really old drivers. However, when you have dashed lines overlapping normal lines, you sometimes are even able to see them on the pdf file itself, you don't even need to print it.

Comment: (what happened is that a point was skipped by the drivers, and a line straight through the middle of the image appeared on all copies for my students...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you increase the number of overlaid lines, you'll realize a shadow effect more and more intense. If you care about aesthetics, you should avoid overlaps.

So, the answer to your question will strongly depend on (a) how precise your printer is (precision changes with brand, models, and print settings like quality, etc), (b) how sensitive are the people who will see your hard copy to detect the difference between the printed paths. Then **"problem"** is a relative term.

I agree with you that it becomes difficult to detect while you are runing PDF. Buuuut... since there are only two overlaid lines, I wouldn't care that much...